# Node.js helmet and swagger-ui

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-ui, helmet.js

I am using a swagger for API documentation in Node.js.
Now I want to use helmet for security, but when I am using helmet, error occur.
However, if I place the helmet below the router for swagger, then it works fine, which means helmet do something that makes swagger-ui not be loaded.

Below code is how I used helmet.

```
var helmet = require('helmet')
app.use(helmet());
```

Below image is the error from swagger

[image]

Fix to allow cors but still got an error.

```
//allow cors
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
  });
  
// use helmet
var helmet = require('helmet')
app.use(helmet());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable CORS , so that it sends the Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * header in responses.
CORS stands for cross origin resource sharing. It opens up the content we intend to server to public for universal JavaScript/browser access.

example:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "YOUR-DOMAIN.TLD"); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

Comment: Thanks!! can you tell me which part of helmet disables the CORS? I could not find it in the documentation

Comment: Check helmet 's contentSecurityPolicy in reference section of their documentation on github.

Comment: It worked at first in Safari browser, but after refresh the page, it does not work..

Answer (score 0):

Always make sure to render the Swagger UI template before setting up the HelmetJS middleware to avoid issues.

```js
// before
const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, new DocumentBuilder().build());
SwaggerModule.setup('docs', app, document);

// then
app.use(helmet());
```

[resource](https://dev.to/starlingroot/helmetjs-and-swaggerui-avoiding-headaches-in-your-nodejs-app-29l3)